# How to get the nonsquare mimo system inverse using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Here I've nonsqaure mimo system 'G' with 3 inputs and 7 outputs:

```
A = [-6.932e-2,17.41,-36.75,0,0,0,-6.0660,-31.54,0;
    -1.435e-4,2.719e-2,-1.411e-3,3.467e-1,0,-9.380e-1,7.139e-2,-1.691e-2,0;
    -4.537e-4,1.870e-3,-2.025e-1,0,1,0,-4.688e-2,7.563e-3,0;
    -1.304e-4,-7.179,-4.916e-1,-6.172e-1,-3.689e-2,7.631e-1,0,0,0;
    2.297e-5,0,-8.667e-1,4.393e-2,-1.947e-1,-2.026e-2,0,0,0;
    1.964e-5,4.263e-2,-1.329e-2,1.233e-3,1.579e-2,-1.600e-1,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,1,1.941e-1,2.771e-1,0,6.258e-2,0;
    0,0,0,0,8.192e-1,-5.736e-1,-5.612e-2,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,6.055e-1,8.648e-1,0,2.006e-2,0]


B = [0,0,-7.560,9.067e-4;
     -6.952e-3,1.293e-2,0,0;
     0,0,-3.425e-2,-9.577e-7;
     4.249,5.989e-1,0,0;
     0,0,-1.796,0;
     -7.287e-2,-2.877e-1,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0]


C = [0,-5.758e-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0;
     0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0;
     0,2.719e-2,-1.411e-3,3.467e-1,0,-9.380e-1,7.139e-2,0,0]


D = [-1.298e-1,-1.610e-1,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0;
     -6.952e-3,1.293e-2,0,0]

 Gss = ss(A,B,C,D)
 G = tf(Gss)
```

I've tried to get the inverse of G using `pinv(G)` but I've got this error:

```
Undefined function 'svd' for input arguments of type 'tf'.

Error in pinv (line 18)
[U,S,V] = svd(A,'econ');
```

Also I've tried to `G'*inv(G*G')` but the result was:

```
    *GT*invGGT
    ans =

      From input 1 to output...
       1:  NaN

       2:  NaN

       3:  NaN

       4:  NaN

      From input 2 to output...
```

...
    Static gain.*

How can I get `inv(G)`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to use a pseudo-inverse system? Is it for system identification? The pinv-command is only for matrices and not for transfer functions.

I think it is very obvious, that inv(G) is completly impossible. How do you want to obtain an inverse function if number of inputs is not equal number of outputs?

Now to your problem: Obviously, you have 7 outputs and want to find the least square solution that fits best to it. I would claim that it is mathematically very difficult, because the observability of the state-space system is not given. ( Try to reduce the number of states, but even then the D-matrix will cause problems.)  The command

```
rank(obsv(Gss))
```

delivers 8 and the system has 9 states. Basically, it means that you cannot observe all the states and thus you cannot deduce the inputs of the states.

Remark: Use the gramians if you want to proof the observability (for scientific reasearch). Obsv has sometimes some numerical problems.